# Internationalization: Are IP Addresses entered in the same format for all cultures?

Tags: language-agnostic, internationalization, ip

I know that IPv4 addresses are written using the dot-decimal notation. What I don't know is if each of the numeric characters entered for an IP Address is always an Arabic numeral (such as 1,2,3...) or if a non-ASCII numeral character is generally accepted for IP Address input?

For instance, if I had a IPv4 address input field localized for a Chinese culture, would it be reasonable for me to only expect Arabic numerals to be entered for each octet? Should I also expect non-ASCII characters that are also numeric?

- This field would be purely for IP Address entry and would not accept host names.

Comment: Well, you can also enter them in hexadecimal

Comment: Understood, I guess my question was in regards to ASCII versus non-ASCII.

Comment: Good question, considering that some countries use a `,` for decimal points.

Comment: @SteveKuo - not for IP addresses, the IP address format is an international standard.

Answer (score 3):

Unicode and ASCII characters are the same for numerics. So yes, IP address should be the same format for all cultures.

The dotted-octet format is an international standard, this should not deviate based on culture.

Answer (score 2):

a. The dot notation for numeric IP addresses is just shorthand / easy read for a direct binary equivalent.

b. It's a programmatic identifier, not a URI/text based field - so no question of internationalization.

So yes, arabic numerals all the way.

I think you would be in trouble the day you could type C# (or anything else) in another language and still have it work seamlessly. Ex. HelloWorld() and नमस्तेविश्व() -- Hindi

But so will we all :)

EDIT: Saw the comment about decimal points - don't let it be an input. Again since it's a programmatic identifier, so decimals are a fixed part of the notation.

Answer (score 1):

IP Address format is standardized and must be the same for all cultures, since network devices actually depends on this exact format. So the obvious answer is, yes you might expect regular numbers and dots only.
There are some other conventions as well, for instance you might use octal IP Addresses, but frankly, I don't see any reason to accept anything but typical IP Address format.